# How can I center my posts and pages in blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I want to center my blog body (Posts and Pages) in blogger, its a custom template
Link: [www.temsah.ga](https://www.temsah.ga)

I tried adding this code below `</b:skin>` :

```
    <style>
#sidebar-atas1
{
display: none;
}
#main-wrapper
{
width: 100%; background:#fff;
}
</style>
```

It removed the sidebar successfully but it didn't center my body.

Comment: can u please provide the help code so that we can help you better!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website. The issue is that your template provides space for the sidebar..
Set your `.portfolio-wrap` width to 100%. That should fix it.

```
.portfolio-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a div that should contain all the html you want to center

```
     <div class="center">
       /*Your html goes here*/
    </div>
```

And Here is the css for it

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.